# react-router-dom: Invalid hook call, Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I try to nest a route: I have a catalog of products in a **Catalog** component, which matches with url *"backoffice/catalog"*.

I want to route to **Edition** component if the url matches with *"backoffice/catalog/edit"*, but I need the **Edition** component to be a child of **Catalog** to share props.

I really don't understand why the nested route doesn't work, please save me ! And don't hesitate to tell me if anything is wrong with my App, I know JavaScript well, but I'm starting with React.

Here is my App component:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./components/Static/Home.js";
import { Dashboard } from "./components/Backoffice/Dashboard.js";
import { Catalog } from "./components/Backoffice/catalog/Catalog.js";
import { Login } from "./components/Login/Login.js";
import { Signup } from "./components/Signup/Signup.js";
import { PrivateRoute } from "./components/PrivateRoute.js";
import "./scss/App.scss";
import {Header} from "./components/Structure/Header";
import {BOHeader} from "./components/Structure/Backoffice/Header";
import {List} from "./components/Listing/List";

function App()
{
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-content">
          <Switch>
              <Route path='/backoffice' component={BOHeader} />
              <Route path='/' component={Header} />
          </Switch>
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} />
              <Route path='/listing' component={List}/>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/backoffice' component={Dashboard}/>
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/backoffice/catalog' component={Catalog}/>
          </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Catalog component (the route is made in the render method:

```js
import React from 'react';
import Data from '../../../Utils/Data';
import {Product} from './Product';
import {Edition} from './Edition';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link,
    useRouteMatch,
    useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

export class Catalog extends React.Component
{
    state = {
        title: '',
        products: [],
        editionProduct: null
    };

    obtainProducts = () =>
    {
        Data.products.obtain()
            .then(products => {this.setState({products: products});})
    };

    editProductHandler = product =>
    {
        this.setState({editionProduct: product});
    };

    saveProductHandler = product =>
    {
        Data.products.save(product).then(() => {
            this.state.products.map(item => {
                item = item._id === product._id ? product : item;
                return item;
            })
        });
    };

    deleteProductHandler = event =>
    {
        const productId = event.target.closest('.product-actions').dataset.productid;
        let products = this.state.products.filter(product => {
            return product._id !== productId;
        });
        this.setState({products: products}, () => {
            Data.products.remove(productId);
        });
    };

    displayProducts = () =>
    {
        return this.state.products.map(product => {
           return (
                <li key={product._id} className='catalog-item'>
                   <Product
                       deleteProductHandler={this.deleteProductHandler}
                       editProductHandler={this.editProductHandler}
                       data={product}
                   />
               </li>
            )
        });
    };


    componentWillMount()
    {
        this.obtainProducts();
    }

    render() {
        const Products = this.displayProducts();
        let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
        return (
            <div className={this.state.editionProduct ? 'catalog edit' : 'catalog'}>
                <h1>Catalog</h1>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={path}>
                        <ul className='catalog-list'>{Products}</ul>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path={`${path}/edit`}>
                        <Edition saveProductHandler={this.saveProductHandler} product={this.state.editionProduct} />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't use hooks inside `Catalog` component because it is a class component. So you have two ways to resolve your issue:

1. Rewrite your component from class to functional.
2. Do not use `useRouteMatch` inside `Catalog` component. If you need to get `match` data inside a component, you need to use [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) high-order component.

So if you select second way, you will need to wrap your `Catalog` component in `withRouter`:

```
export default withRouter(Catalog);
```

Change one row in `render` function from:

```
let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
```

To:

```
const { path, url } = this.props.match;
```

And do not forget to change the import of your `Catalog` component, because now your component exports as default.

Answer (score 8):

As I had the same issue when setting up my React Router with Typescript, I will detail a little bit more Andrii answer in 4 steps:

### 1 - npm/yarn packages

```
yarn add react-router-dom --save
yarn add @types/react-router-dom --save-dev
```

or

```
npm install react-router-dom --save
npm install @types/react-router-dom --save-dev
```

### 2 - index.tsx

---

1) When importing your higher order component (App in the present case), do not use curly brackets as App will be exported as default;

2) BrowserRouter needs to be in a upper level rather the class that will be exported as "default withRouter(Class)", in order to prevent the following error:

> "You should not use Route or withRouter() outside a Router"

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import App from './app';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

### 3 - app.tsx

---

1) Import from **react-router-dom**, withRouter & RouteComponentProps (or your own PropType definition);

2) Extend React.Component and use the RouteComponentProps interface;

3) Pass the props to components you want to share routing data;

4) Export the higher order class as **default withRouter**.

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ExpensesPage } from './pages/expenses/expenses.page';
import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home.page';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import './app.scss';

class App extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  public render(): ReactElement {
    return (
      <div className='playground'>
        <HeaderComponent {...this.props} />
        <div className="playground-content">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} {...this.props} />
            <Route exact path='/expenses' component={ExpensesPage} {...this.props} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

### 4 - header.component

---

Through your RouteComponentProps extending your class, you can access normally the routing props as history, location and match as bellow:

```js
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import './header.component.scss';

export class HeaderComponent extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  public render(): ReactElement {
    const { location } = this.props;
    console.log(location.pathname);

    return (
      <header className="header">
        {/* ... */}
      </header >
    );
  }
}
```

Hope it helps because I had a bit of challenge to make this works in a simple environment with webpack and no redux. Last time working properly with the following versions:

```
{
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
},
{
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `useParams` when you export like:

```
export default (props) => <NewComponent {...props} {...useParams()} />
```

Full example:

```
<Route exact path='/event/:id' element={<NewComponent />}/>

inport {useParams } from "react-router-dom";

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.id}</div>
  }
}

// Bind url parameters here
export default (props) => <NewComponent {...useParams()} {...props} />
```